# pandas column modification with regular expression

Tags: python, database, pandas, python-re

i want to fix some string entries in pandas series, such that all values with pattern '0x.202' (last digit of year is missing) will be appended with one zero at the end (so that it is the full date of format 'mm.yyyy'). Here is the pattern i got:

```
pattern = '\d*\.202(?:$|\W)'
```

Matches exactly the 2 digits separated by point and exactly 202 in the end. Could you please help me with the way how to replace the strings in series, while preserving original indexes?

My current way to do this is:

```
date = df['Calendar Year/Month'].astype('str')
pattern = re.compile('\d*\.202(?:$|\W)')
date.str.replace(pattern, pattern.pattern + '0', regex=True)
```

but i get an error:

```
error: bad escape \d at position 0
```

Edit: Sorry for lack of details, i forgot to mention that dates were misinterpreted by pandas as floats, so that is why dates with year 2020 were not completely shown (5.2020 is rounded to 5.202, for example). So the expression i used:

```
date = df['Year/Month'].astype('str')
date = date.apply(lambda _: _ if _[-1] == '1' or _[-1] == '9' else f'{_}0')
```

So that only 'xx.202' are edited and dates like 'xx.2021' and 'xx.2019' are omitted. Thanks everyone for help!

Comment: maybe `re.compile(r'\d*\.202(?:$|\W)')` ?

Comment: Thanks for noticing, but still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to use regex here? If not, this would work (add a 0 if the length of the string is x).

```
df["Calendar Year/Month"].apply(lambda _: _ if len(_)==7 else f'{_}0')
```

Or maybe this (add a 0 if the last digit is 2):

```
df["Calendar Year/Month"].apply(lambda _: _ if _[-1] == 0 else f'{_}0')
```

Comment: hey, thanks for answer, nice approach, but there are dates like '12.202', for example, which should be modified as well

Comment: Hey Bollo7, I've added a new approach which could work also

Comment: The last variant works for me! that's what i used "date = date.apply(lambda _: _ if _[-1] == '1' or _[-1] == '9' else f'{_}0')" . Adds zeros to only strings, that are not with 9 or 1 in the end (omits 2019 and 2021). Sorry for lack of details, i forgot to mention that dates were misinterpreted by pandas as floats, so that is why dates with year 2020 were not completely shown (5.2020 is rounded to 5.202, for example).

Comment: Glad to help! This approach should be faster than regex as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do a `str.replace`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year/Month':['10.202 abc', 'abc 1.202']})
df['Year/Month'].str.replace(r'(\d*\.202)\b', r'\g<1>0')
```

Output:

```
0    10.2020 abc
1    abc 1.2020
Name: Year/Month, dtype: object
```

Comment: hey, your approach works for all the values with one digit in the start, but how to approach dates like '11.202' as well?